# Problema com array_search

Tags: php, array, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho a `array` abaixo que está dando um problema.

Quando dou um search ele só busca alguns valores ele não esta encontrando o 2018-06-11,
2018-06-18 e o
2018-06-26

O restante funciona perfeitamente

```
$hoje = "2018-06-11";
 $diario = array(
    "0.25" => "2018-06-11",
    "0.35" => "2018-06-12",
    "0.38" => "2018-06-13",
    "0.50" => "2018-06-14",
    "0.00" => "2018-06-15",
    "0.25" => "2018-06-18",
    "0.37" => "2018-06-19",
    "0.25" => "2018-06-20",
    "0.23" => "2018-06-21",
    "0.45" => "2018-06-22",
    "0.33" => "2018-06-25",
    "0.28" => "2018-06-26",
    "0.40" => "2018-06-27",
    "0.31" => "2018-06-28",
    "0.28" => "2018-06-29",
    "0.32" => "2018-07-03"
    );


echo $lucrohoje = array_search($hoje, $diario);
```

Comment: O array tem chaves iguais logo a última é a que prevalece. Pode ver que o array vai ter menos elemento use o `var_dump()` ou o `print_r()` para conferir.

Comment: É esse o problema, deveria ser ao contrário talvez? A data como chave.

Comment: Desde que a chave não se repita não tem problema, não sei se esse é o caso.

Comment: OK realmente era esse o problema, muito obrigado

Comment: Parece ser sim. E até deixa de ser necessário usar o `array_search`. Basta `<?php echo $diario[$hoje] ?>` (Confirmando que a chave existe claro)